# Submit form to new custom size window

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I know this is a dumb question, but I haven't been able to find a precise answer to my specific issue. I have tried changing the submit button to a regular button and adding an `onClick` event... no dice. I am trying to submit a form to a new, custom-sized window (so not a new tab in Chrome, etc). I have gotten it so it opens the submitted form data on the new page in a new window, but the custom sized-window is also opened as a blank page.

```
<form action="Upload.cfm" target="_blank" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onSubmit="window.open('', 'mywindow3','left=0,width=900,height=600,z-index=20, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes');">
```

If i remove the onSubmit javascript, it just opens a new tab (again, not what I want). If i remove the `target="_blank"`, it just opens a new tab as well.

What I really want to do is have the `window.open` dimensions in my onSubmit event apply to the submitted form page, not an extraneous blank page.

Comment: If my post is unclear, the above code opens 2 pop-up windows (1 good, 2 bad). The custom-sized one is not the page the form submits too, unfortunately. The one the page submits to is a little smaller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

Set the action normally, set a custom name for the `target` attribute and set the `button` type to `button`, not `submit` (we will submit by javascript):

```
<form id="myform" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="Upload.cfm" target="result">
    <input type="text" name="test" value="test">
    <button type="button" id="mybutton">Send</button>
</form>
```

Set a "click" event to the `button` and, in the callback, open the window with `window.open()` and set the first parameter as the form's action and the **second parameter as the form's target** as well as the dimensions and furthermore attributes. And then submit the form!

```
document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener('click', function(){
  window.open('Upload.cfm', 'result', 'width=300,height=300');
  document.getElementById('myform').submit();
});
```

I've tested this in latest Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

A (bit) simpler version and explanation than the answer above, imo:

```
<form action="Upload.cfm" method="POST" target="customWindow">
  <input type="text" name="test" value="test">
  <button onclick="window.open('Upload.cfm', 'customWindow', 'width=900,height=600'); $(this).closest('form').submit();">
           SUBMIT
  </button> 
</form>
```