# Grails opens a new window but I am unable to specify the window size. How do I use G:actionSubmit to open a smaller window?

Tags: html, grails, groovy

I am using Grails and I'm trying to pop up a new window which is smaller that the window I am in, so I've tried this which works, except the new window is full size.

```
<g:form controller="myController">      
  <g:actionSubmit value="View the New Page" action="index" formtarget="_blank" params="width=200, height=500"/> 
</g:form>
```

How can I make the new window smaller?  The params bit in my code doesn't seem to do much to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in JavaScript using onclick:

```
<g:actionSubmit value="View the New Page" onclick="window.open('/URL', 'customWindow', 'width=100,height=100'); return false;"/>
```

[Submit form to new custom size window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28903144/submit-form-to-new-custom-size-window)